# How to get index without counting the hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the index of clicked element. This works fine so far.

Problem is that you can `hide` elements. If an element is hidden I don't want it to be "counted" in the index.

If you have a look at the fiddle and all boxes are orange the index is how it should be. If you click on `Click me to hide some divs` -- they don't get removed, in reality they get a `display:none;` here they just get another color to give you an idea -- they also get the class `hidden` so now I don't want the index to index them. But if I click on `Div 2` I would like the index to show **`1`**

I've tried with `$('div').not('hidden')` fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/rva54sy3/2/

```
<script>
(function($){
    var indexBoxes = function(e) {
        $element = $(this);
        var index = $element.not('.hidden').index();
        $( "h3.txt" ).text( "That was div index #" + index );
    }
    $(document).on( 'click', '.getIndex', indexBoxes);
})(jQuery);

$('.hide-some-divs').on('click',function(){
    $('.hide').addClass('hidden').closest('.wrap').addClass('hidden');
});
</script>

<h3 class="txt">Click a div!</h3>
<div class="wrap clearfix">
    <div class="getIndex">Div 0</div>
    <div class="getIndex hide">Div 1</div>
    <div class="getIndex">Div 2</div>
    <div class="getIndex hide">Div 3</div>
    <div class="getIndex">Div 4</div>
    <div class="getIndex hide">Div 5</div>
</div>

<div class="hide-some-divs">Click me to hide some divs</div>
```

and if you like some styling:

```
<style>
.getIndex {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:orange;
    float:left;
}
.wrap.hidden > div.hide {
    background-color:#fafafa;
}
.hide-some-divs {
    background-color:#afafff;
    padding:10px;cursor:pointer;
    margin:20px auto;
    width:250px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the index like this way

```
(function($) {
    var indexBoxes = function(e) {
        var index = $(".getIndex").not('.hidden').index(this);
        $("h3.txt").text("That was div index #" + index);
    }
    $(document).on('click', '.getIndex', indexBoxes);
})(jQuery);
```

This will the index of given element corresponding to your selected list(not related to the immediate parent). Here the selected element list is `.getIndex` class divs which doesnt have the class name `.hidden`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rva54sy3/4/)

Comment: Can you exaplain it please?

Comment: Inside the `.not()` goes another css selector. You used `'hidden'`, which would try to select an element `<hidden>`. Instead, you needed to look for the class, which is why this answer works: it uses the class selector `'.hidden'`

Comment: `$(this).index()` will return the index compared to all it's siblings regardless if it's hidden or not - by doing `$(".getIndex").not('.hidden').index(this)` you are getting the index of the current element compared to the set of elements in the selector

Comment: Thanks @anoop but how can I get the index if I have more then just one `wrap`? soo something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rva54sy3/5/

Comment: @caramba can you explain more about the scenario?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yes! I could also open a new question if this goes to far!? problem is (in reality) I have more than just one `<div class="wrap">` which has divs inside which can be set to hidden. so I have to check if which `<div class="wrap">` did the click happen and just index over those `divs` in the `wrap` ... so something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rva54sy3/5/ but with working index()

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.inArray() to get the index of clicked element from visible elements.

```
(function($){
    var indexBoxes = function(e) {
        $element = $(this);
        var index = ($.inArray((this),$(".getIndex").not(".hidden")));
        $( "h3.txt" ).text( "That was div index #" + index );
    }
    $(document).on( 'click', '.getIndex', indexBoxes);
})(jQuery);
```

Here's [a link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayurRahul/b286m6mt/)!

Comment: thanks Mayur but it's not what I want: Now the index is not working if the boxes are not hidden..

Comment: @caramba : Yeah have alook again , updated the class to hidden. Before   it was wrong class in selection. Its working now.

Comment: Thanks Mayur! now it works, now maybe I have to open a new question. My problem now is that I might have more then just on `<div class="wrap">` something like this http://jsfiddle.net/b286m6mt/1/ how can I make the index() to work then?

Comment: i am not clear with the problem, can u explain more. Its working great here too.

Comment: You mean if you have multiple <div class="wrap"> ... </div>. In that case you can use    var index = ($.inArray((this),$(".wrap > .getIndex").not(".hidden")));

Answer (score 0):

In case you would actually hide them, you could use:

```
var index = $(".getIndex:visible").index(this);
```

The selector only counts elements with a class `.getIndex` that are also visible (aka not `display: none`)

However, that won't work with your example, because you use a background color to "fake" hiding them.

Comment: The `:visible` selector is much more complicated than that. It will check if is has `visibility:visible;` and if all of it's parents match the selector `:visible` too.